# Find the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{\left({s}^{2}+{1}\right)^{2}}$.

Tags: laplace-transform

What is Laplace inverse of

$$\dfrac{1}{\left({s}^{2}+{1}\right)^{2}}$$

Comment: Please share your thoughts on the problem, and explain what you've tried as well as what you do understand about the question.

Comment: I know that if it is \dfrac{-2s}{\left({s}^{2}+{1}\right)^{2}} . Its laplace inverse would be tsint. By using formula Laplace inverse{F'(s)}= tf(t)

Comment: Is convolution going to help here? like splitting into two terms 1/(s^2 +1) and applying laplace?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\dfrac{1}{(s^2 + \omega^2)^2}\right] = \dfrac{1}{2 \omega^3}\left(\sin \omega t - \omega t \cos \omega t \right)$$

Note: $\omega$ is a real constant in this generalization.

Now, can you find the Laplace transform of $\sin \omega t$ and $\omega t \cos \omega t$ to understand what is going on with one of the shift theorems and why this is the result?

Of course you can always use the formal definitions to find this also if that is the approach required.

Comment: Nice work! $+1$

Comment: Ahhh, indeed! POETS Day! (Btw, I reworked the "bird in flight" question which you answered earlier. It dawned on me that there was a "unit conversion issue".)

Comment: Ahhh, no, I meant even more of a units issue: $x$ given in kmph, and other rates and distances given in meters per second. See the question and my answer.

Comment: @amWhy: I removed my answer as I did not review his work in detail. Also, you are missing $x's$ in third row from bottom. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

We can use the residue theorem to evaluate this inverse Laplace transform.  Consider the following contour integral in the complex $s$ plane:

$$\oint_C \frac{ds}{(s^2+1)^2}  e^{s t}$$

where $C$ is a Bromwich contour, in that the contour integral is equal to

$$\int_{c-i R}^{c+i R} ds \frac{e^{s t}}{(s^2+1)^2} + i R \int_{\pi/2}^{3 \pi/2} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \frac{e^{R t e^{i \theta}}}{(R^2 e^{i 2 \theta}+1)^2}$$

where $c \ge 0$ (and is defined so that the vertiical line piece of $c$ is to the right of the rightmost pole).  For $t \gt 0$, the second integral is bounded by

$$\frac{2}{R^3} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{-R t \sin{\theta}} \le \frac{2}{R^3} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{-2 R t \theta/\pi} \le \frac{\pi}{R^4 t} $$

Thus, when $t \gt 0$, the second integral vanishes as $1/R^4$ as $R \to\infty$.  Therefore, by the residue theorem,

$$\frac{1}{i 2 \pi} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} ds \frac{e^{s t}}{(s^2+1)^2} = \sum_{\pm}\text{Res}_{s=\pm i} \frac{e^{s t}}{(s^2+1)^2}$$

The residues on the RHS are computed as follows because the poles are double poles:

$$\text{Res}_{s=\pm i} \frac{e^{s t}}{(s^2+1)^2} = \left [ \frac{d}{ds} \frac{e^{s t}}{(s \pm i)^2} \right ]_{z=\pm i} = \left [ \frac{(t (s \pm i)^2-2 (s \pm i)) e^{s t}}{(s \pm i)^4}\right]_{s=\pm i}$$

Note that for $t \lt 0$, we close the Bromwich contour to the right, so that there are no poles enclosed within $c$ and the ILT is identically zero.

Thus, the ILT is, for $t \gt 0$

$$\frac{(2 i)^2 t-4 i}{(2 i)^4} e^{i t} + \frac{(-2 i)^2 t + 4 i}{(-2 i)^4} e^{-i t} = -\frac{t}{2} \cos{t} + \frac12 \sin{t}$$

and $0$ otherwise.